# Grid lines are not printing

Tags: php, css, gridview, datagrid

i have grid and print icon..if i click print icon i should print the grid.but grid lines are not showing in the printout.

What should i do?

Here is my code

```
<div style="float: right" id="hide_div"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="printPage('pnlMainHeader','div_print');"><img src="<?=$this->baseUrl('/images/icons/small/print.png')?>" title="Print" alt="Print" /></a></div>
<div class="clear10"></div>
<div class="pnlMainHeader" id="pnlMainHeader" style="display: none; ">
    //some xyz code
</div>
<div class="clear10"></div>
<div id="div_print">
    //grid code
    <?=$this->TemplateRoles?>
</div>
```

and onclick printPage code in .js file

```
function printPage(printpage1, printpage2)
{   
var hideDiv = document.getElementById('hide_div')
hideDiv.style.display = 'none';

var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
var footstr = "</body>";
var newstr1 = document.getElementById(printpage1).innerHTML;
var newstr2 = document.getElementById(printpage2).innerHTML;    
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr1+newstr2+footstr;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
location.reload();
return false;
}
```

please help me..

Comment: Any chance you could show the `css` for `clear10`? Might be something funky in that.

Comment: Hi Fluffeh,,thanks for ur responce here is the css code .clear10
{
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
 height: 10px;
}

Answer (score 0):

What if you were to add another css file to the header that will force the borders to print?  Something like this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Then inside the file, you can use that class or selector with something like this:

```
.gridClass /*(or "td" or whatever it is called)*/ { border:1px solid #000;}
```

Whatever is named in the print.css will only appear when printed because you specify the medium.  I hope that helps.